# Programmatically adding conditional formatting in Excel 2007

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I want to use conditional formatting feature of excel 2007 programmatically. I have following scenario.

I have 6 columns of numbers

```
A   B  C  D  E  F
100 25 25 15 20 50
....
```

`if (C1/A1)*100 >= B1` I have to color it as red. The same rule applies to D1, E1,F1 columns.

I saw conditional formatting feature in excel 2007. But I want some pointers on how to implement it in C# code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Google knows pretty well what to do)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're happy to use Interop, since you didn't say otherwise. Here's what I use to set conditional formatting in Excel. It assumes you already have your `Worksheet` referenced in a variable called `xlWorksheet`.

```
// Create a FormatCondition and add it to the specified range of cells, using the
// passed-in condition and cell colour

Excel.Range range = xlWorksheet.get_Range("C1", "C1");
Excel.FormatConditions fcs = range.FormatConditions;
Excel.FormatCondition fc = (Excel.FormatCondition)fcs.Add
    (Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Type.Missing, "=IF($C$1/$A$1)*100 >= $B$1");
Excel.Interior interior = fc.Interior;
interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
interior = null;
fc = null;
fcs = null;
range = null;
```

I've guessed a bit at your intended usage but you can fiddle with it to get the formulae and cell references right.

Comment: thnx for the answer. But when I use the code Im getting following error Message = "Method not found: 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatCondition Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatConditions.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionType, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object)'."

Comment: @Rajneesh Sorry, there was a typo in my code on that line. I didn't close the bracket properly. Give it another go. If it still doesn't work, show the statement that's causing the error.

Comment: VS Intillesense is showing an error when I use add method with 3 params. So, I have used FormatCondition formatCondition = (Excel.FormatCondition)formatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Type.Missing, "=D2/B2*100>=C2", Type.Missing); But, on executing the code it is showing the error which I have mentioned in my earlier comment.

Comment: @Rajneesh I've just been reading that there are some late-binding issues with certain versions of the Interop and .NET assemblies. You mentioned you're using Excel 2007, but which version of the Interop assemblies do you have referenced, and what version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: @Rajneesh And have a look at this question, it seems to be the same issue you are having: [Excel Interop: Range.FormatConditions.Add throws MissingMethodException](http://stackoverflow.com/q/644822/976080)

Comment: What if I want to set formatting condition on duplicate entry of a column?

Comment: Hi @Si8, I'm afraid I haven't touched this type of stuff for a few years now and have forgotten much of it. I suggest you try and find another question similar to yours, or if you can't find one then start a new post yourself.

Comment: @Sid Holland. Thank you... I was able to figure it out.